# Using a VBA script to login to a website Login Page

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, automation

I am trying to use sources on google and on this site to help me but I am struggling to enter a username and password to a input box on a login page.

The page is on a local network on our work server.

The HTML code for the login page:

```
<TD background=/frontend/images/greenback.gif width=302><INPUT maxLength=32 name=username> </TD>

<TD background=/frontend/images/greenback.gif width=302><INPUT maxLength=32 type=password value="" name=password> </TD>
```

So far I have tried:

```
Sub Test()

On Error Resume Next

Dim sUrl As String: sUrl = "https://workplace.plus.net/index.html?"
Dim ie As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True

ie.navigate sUrl

Do While ie.readystate <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

ie.document.getElement.Name("username").Value = 1234

End Sub
```

I have also tried:

```
ie.document.getElement.Name("username").Value = 1234
ie.document.getElement.Id("username").Value = 1234
ie.document.getElement.Class("username").Value = 1234
ie.document.getElement.Type("username").Value = 1234

ie.document.getElementByClassName("username").Value = 1234
ie.document.getElementById("username").Value = 1234
ie.document.getElementByName("username").Value = 1234
ie.document.getElementByType("username").Value = 1234
```

The thing is I used this same code on google with the ID button and it works. Is there something I am not taking into consideration?

Comment: Try to save as this page and seek in the code for ID, probably ID of username is different.

Comment: There is no ID tag

Comment: I meant tag for username, seeking in code of saved page can be the only way to find username id.

Comment: Firstly, this `ie.document.getElement.Name()` doesn't exist and it won't work. Same goes for all your attempts that follow this kind of syntax. The correct method looks like `ie.document.getElementsByName("username")`. Mind the "s" in there! It means the method returns a collection of elements whose Name attribute equals "username". To access the first member of this collection you do it like so `ie.document.getElementsByName("username")(0)`.

Comment: ie.document.querySelector("[name=username]").value = "somevalue")

Answer (score 0):

Here i'm using the facebook login page. You can put any other link to login, put sUser as string and sPass as string. Assigned the values you want to input.   Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")) is the time between loading the page and add login id and password. On the other hand will pass the user id and password  IE.Document.all.Item("email").Value = sUser. Try this code please

```
Sub facebookPost()
Dim IE As Object
Dim sUser As String, sPass As String


sUser = "1234"
sPass = "1234"

Set IE = CreateObject("INTERNETEXPLORER.Application")

IE.Navigate ("www.Facebook.com")
IE.Visible = True

Do While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))

IE.Document.all.Item("email").Value = sUser
IE.Document.all.Item("pass").Value = sPass
IE.Document.all.Item("loginbutton").Click
End Sub
```